# Handling a promise in a Ionic/Cordova Application

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angular-promise

I'm currently working on a `Ionic/Cordova` application, a to-do application. I am using the `ngCordova` library for an easier use of the cordova plugins.  I'm also using the `Sqlite` plugin by `litehelpers` ([GitHub page](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage)).

My problem is about the correct understanding of the JavaScript's promises behavior. I have a Angular service called "Projects", which make use of the SQLite plugin, and a "Tasks" controller which is delegated to it.

```js
angular.module('myapp.services', [])

.factory("Projects", ["$ionicPlatform", "$cordovaSQLite", "$window", "$q",
  function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite, $window, $q) {
    return {
      // SOME FUNCTIONS..
      getCurrentProject: function() {
        var q = $q.defer();

        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
          $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 
              "SELECT id_project, name FROM projects WHERE active = 1").then(
              function(res) {

              q.resolve(res.rows.item(0));
          }, function(err) {
            q.reject(err);
            console.error(err.message);
          });
        });

        return q.promise;
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

I want to make this function return an object, which is the result of my query.

The `promises` and `callback` keywords are confusing me.

I've tried a few ways to solve my problem, but when I call (in my controller):

```
var currentProject = Projects.getCurrentProject();
```

And then trying to check its values with:

```
console.log("ID -> " + currentProject.id_project);
console.log("NAME -> " + currentProject.name);
```

I always get `undefined`.  How do I handle a `promise` in a Ionic/Cordova Application?

### Solved

@bardzusny's answer totally made me realize where i was wrong, thank you all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises are designed to be chainable with error handling and final behavior (optional), like so:

```
Projects.getCurrentProject()
.then (project) -> currentProject = project
.catch (err) -> console.error err
.finally () -> wrapUpFn()
```

So you would need to use `.then` to make the assignment.  Otherwise you're assigning currentProject to the promise object, not the result of the promise object (which is what you want).

**EDIT**

Now in javascript :)

```
var currentProject

Projects.getCurrentProject()
.then(function(project) {
  currentProject = project
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.error(err)
})
.finally(function() {
  wrapUpFn()
})
```

As an aside, promise objects are great because you can just keep on chaining down the line with `.then`s, and still keep your error handling and final behaviors clear.  This lets you create simple flows that are ordered within the crazy world of javascript.

Comment: Good answer, +1 (beat me to it) - only issue I have with it, it doesn't look like JavaScript for me. Not sure if it's some Coffee Script dialect (never got into this stuff), but don't you think it would be better to provide vanilla, working example? One thing I definitely see missing here is providing actual functions to `.then()`, `.catch()` methods ("`.then(function(result) { ... });`").

Comment: Yes, it's coffeescript.  I didn't even notice while I was typing it... sigh.  Anyway, translated into JS now!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now in my controller i act like this:
var currentProject = Projects.getCurrentProject().then(function(res){ return res; });
Is it good?

Comment: I don't believe that will work.  I think you will need to make the actual variable assignment inside of the `.then` (see my example above).  Otherwise `currentProject` is immediately assigned to the promise object, rather than being `undefined` for split second and then being assigned to the `project` once `getCurrentProject()` returns.